# SendMessage fails while sending RTF file to HDC

Tags: c++, winapi, rtf, gdi

I try to print an RTF file to a DC using C/C++.
I'm not able to do by myself so I tried to search on internet and I found a good solution [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=28463). This code seams to work with text only RTF or with RTF which contains pictures. If I try to print some RTF (generated with Microsoft Word) containing complex objects (i.e. charts) the SendMessage(...) function fails and GetLastError() returns (5).

This is the code where I call that function:

```
BOOL FillRichEditFromFile(HWND hwnd){
    BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"RTFchartWord.rtf", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,  NULL);  
    
    EDITSTREAM es = { 0 }; 
    es.pfnCallback = EditStreamCallback;
    es.dwCookie    = (DWORD_PTR)hFile;

    if(ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hwnd,EM_STREAMIN,MSGFLT_ALLOW,NULL)==FALSE)
        std::cout<<"change window message filter failed: "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;

    if (SendMessage(hwnd, EM_STREAMIN, SF_RTF, (LPARAM)&es) && es.dwError == 0) 
        fSuccess = TRUE;
    else
        std::cout<<"SendMessage failed:"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
    
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return fSuccess;
}
```

The callback function which read the file is as follows:

```
DWORD CALLBACK EditStreamCallback(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE lpBuff,LONG cb, PLONG pcb){
    HANDLE hFile = (HANDLE)dwCookie;
    if (ReadFile(hFile, lpBuff, cb, (DWORD *)pcb, NULL)) 
    {
        return 0;
    }    
    return -1;
}
```

According to MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage), SendMessage() fails and GetLastError() returns (5) when UIPI blocks the message.
So I try to allow the message to be received using:

```
if(ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hwnd,EM_FORMATRANGE,MSGFLT_ALLOW,NULL)==FALSE)
    std::cout<<"change window message filter failed: "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

The HWND hwnd if obtained as follow

```
HMODULE hLib=LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));

HWND hwndRTF = CreateWindow(MSFTEDIT_CLASS , NULL,
    ES_MULTILINE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm very new on programming with HWND handle so I'm not sure how to properly fix this problem. If there is no possible solution, can someone suggest me an alternative way to print an RTF file/buffer to DC?

Comment: Please use C++ tag only for these questions, not C. And make sure to use the winapi tag to get the Windows gurus' attention. I fixed the tags.

Comment: Where did you get the hwnd from? Does it belong to your own process?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry I missed this part, I update the question with the part where I obained the hwnd.

Comment: You misread the documentation. It says that `GetLastError` (not `SendMessage`) return 5 (positive 5, not negative 5) when blocked by UIPI. Note also that if the window itself returns 0 as the message result, you will misinterpret it as a `SendMessage` failure. This is a window in the same process, so UIPI does not apply.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes you are right, but it was my bad during the writing of question. Actually Sendmessage() fails end GetLastError() returns (5) as if UIPI blocks the message. Anyway thank you, I correct the question.

Comment: Calling `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx` on your own window just so you can send your own messages to it is wrong. That function is meant to be used when your want *other processes* of lower integrity to send messages to your window, which is not the case here.

Comment: I suspect the `5` is just a left over error code. Since you say that it works with simple RTF files, the problem is definitely not UIPI. (The message is getting through, seeing as simple RTF files work. It's that the control itself doesn't like the complex RTF file. Maybe it's something the system RichText control doesn't support?)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok I understand your point. . Anyway thank you very much, as I said I'm not very expert on windows programming so a make stupid mistakes.

Comment: @RaymondChen hte incompatibility between complex RTF and Richtext is one of my first hypothesis but I didn't find any documentatoin about it so I thought that i made some coding error. Can you suggest an alternative way to print RTF on HDC?